# Finding Limit point of complex sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, analysis

Show that $$a_n:=2^{-n/2}(1+i)^n\frac{1+n}{n}$$ has $i$ as one of its limit points.

To show that one of its limit points is in fact $i$ i thought that i have to find a subsequence with $\lim_{k\to\infty} a_{n_k}=i$. I plotted the first 1000 elements of the sequence and guess that the subsequence with $8k+2, k\in\mathbb{N}$ should be the appropriate one. But I am unfortunately stuck. I wanted to convert the sequence into polar coordinates but didn't really know how to evaluate the absolute value of $a_n$ let alone the angle, because I don't know how to separate the imaginary and real part here.

Comment: If you write $(1+i)$ in polar form $re^i\theta$ then you can see $(1+i)^n = r^n e^{in\theta}$ and so $a_n = 2^{-n/2}\frac{1+n}{n}r^n e^{in\theta} = \tilde{r}e^{in\theta}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have$$a_n=\frac{1+n}n\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\right)^n=\frac{1+n}ne^{\pi in/4},$$since $e^{\pi i/4}=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}$. So,$$a_{8k+2}=\frac{8k+3}{8k+2}i\to_{k\to\infty}i.$$